# Is it haram for an unmarried person to imagine sex?

Tags: halal-haram, zina

Is it haram for an unmarried person to imagining sex.
Will it be considered zina?

Comment: Why should it be? explain!!!... Please put some more effort and information in your question!

Answer (score -1):

No, it is a different sin which is much smaller and is an act of shamfulness.

16:90 says:

Allah commands justice, the doing of good, and liberty to kith and kin, and He forbids all shameful deeds, and injustice and rebellion: He instructs you, that ye may receive admonition. (16:90)

But if you can control your desires there is great reward mentioned in the Quran for this:

And for such as had entertained the fear of standing before their Lord's (tribunal) and had restrained (their) soul from lower Desires, (79:40) Their Abode will be the Garden. (79:41)